# 2004 Mazda 3 - Passenger side window receives signal to go up but not down

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting

I own a Mazda 3.  I have electric windows.  Then passenger side window switch only works to roll the window up.  It does not work to roll the window down.  I have to use the window switches on the driver side to roll the passenger window down.  Does anybody know what is wrong and if it might be an easy fix?  Thanks.

Comment: Passenger window switch is bad, replace it.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the passenger windows switch is bad, you can remove the switch and use an ohm meter to check continuity.

Verify continuity as indicated in the table for all 3 switch positions.

"Closed" is windows up

"Open" is window down. This is the one I suspect does have continuity or very high resistance.

"Off" is neutral position when not being used.

[image]

[image]